# Woocommerce Programmatically change a "simple" product to a "variable" product with variations of downloads and hardcopies

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce (wordpress) up to date, with over 10k products which I need to create variations for, there are four kinds of variations, two are hardcopy with inventory control, the other two variation of the products does not need inventory control.

I have check out so many various ways people have created programmatically variations and attempted their scripts on a dev site, that I am starting to get bug eyed.

```
<?php

require_once('wp-load.php'); // load the wordpress core
require_once('functions.php') ; // custom functions to grab related data from the wpdb

$import_id = GetTheNextProduct(); // non-wordpress database
$is_variable_product = CheckIfVariable($import_id) ;
 $post_id = GetRelatedWPDI($import_id); // returns related word press post `ID` of the product 
 // ... other variables are set in the same way... ie: $sku = GetSKU($import_id) ;
 // the problem I am having is getting the current variation array into woocommerce variations, 
 // I've been able to do everything else.
 if($is_variable_product == 1) {
 $variations = GetVariations($import_id) ;
 // woocommerce proper way to create variations....????
 } 
 /* out example of $variations...

 $variations = array(
 "0" => array(
         "ProductType" => "Small PDF",
         "filepath" => "/path/to/pdf/file.pdf",
         "filename" => "file.pdf",
         "price" => "5.00",
         "_visibility" => "visible",
         "_stock_status" => "instock",
         "_downloadable" => "yes",
         "_weight" => "",
         "_length" => "",
         "_width" => "",
         "_height" => "",
         "_width" => "", 
         "inventory" => "unlimited",
         "_sku" => "parent",
         ),
 "1" => array(
         "ProductType" => "Large PDF",
         "filepath" => "/path/to/pdf/file-large.pdf",
         "filename" => "file-large.pdf",
         "price" => "10.00",
         "_visibility" => "visible",
         "_stock_status" => "instock",
         "_downloadable" => "yes",
         "_weight" => "",
         "_length" => "",
         "_width" => "",
         "_height" => "", 
         "_width" => "",
         "inventory" => "unlimited",
         "_sku" => "parent",
         ),
 "2" => array(
         "ProductType" => "Small Hardcopy",
         "filepath" => "",
         "filename" => "",
         "price" => "15.00",
         "_visibility" => "visible",
         "_stock_status" => "instock",
         "_downloadable" => "yes",
         "_weight" => "0.5",
         "_length" => "",
         "_width" => "8",
         "_height" => "11",
         "_width" => "", 
         "inventory" => "123",
         "_sku" => "parent",
         ),
 "4" => array(
         "ProductType" => "Large Hardcopy",
         "filepath" => "",
         "filename" => "",
         "price" => "20.00",
         "_visibility" => "visible",
         "_stock_status" => "instock",
         "_downloadable" => "yes",
         "_weight" => "0.5",
         "_length" => "",
         "_width" => "8",
         "_height" => "11",
         "_width" => "", 
         "inventory" => "456",
         "_sku" => "parent",
         ),
 )


 */

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', $sku); 
update_post_meta( $post_id,'_visibility','visible');
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'variable', 'product_type');

// do something here to the current $variations array variable to...

$variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

foreach($variations as $vars_sub){
    foreach($vars_sub as $key => $value) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_'.$key, $value );
        }
}
```

I've read, tried, so many of the script suggestions within stack, some which have helped a lot with simple products that remain simple... but this one has me stumped.

Comment: how can this be to broad? ... How do you add four variation to a product in woocommerce, two that are downloads and two that are not.... that's not broad.

Comment: When you add variations to a simple product, doesn't that make it a variable product??

Comment: So here is a real basic question...  I tried looking up a list of the functions for doing things such as  what can be found for wordpress itself... and all I could find was this... https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/package-WooCommerce.Functions.html ... is there anywhere where the documentation is better?

Comment: I don't use Stack that often.  In fact I haven't been on here for a long time. And this little back and forth between is likely the main reason why.

It turns out, I found a very very simple way to this.... although it will be the last time I ever deal with woocommerce, and will not recommend it again to any client... for that matter I think I'm done with wordpress as well... and stack.

Comment: If you have really found a very simple way to do it, share it with the community and answer to your own question. It will helps some other people that are searching the same thing…

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by leveraging WC's REST API and Python.  My script is here: https://gist.github.com/Antebios/f53807040247b536e1674758a400dc45

Converting the product type from 'Simple' to Variable was easy, it was adding the variations that was tricky.  I am doing an iteration loop and creating a variation from an array, I also check if the variation already exists so there are no duplicate variations.  Have a look.